# What is causing this nav bar to look different?

Tags: css, drupal-6

I am working on a Drupal 6 site that some CSS issues.  I have used firebug to try and determine what is causing it, but I am at a loss.

[Messed up nav bar](http://www2.boldspring.com/PictorialAvailability)

[Correct nav bar](http://www2.boldspring.com/node/4)

The page has a custom app that is loaded when you click on the link. I corrected another problem in the custom app stylesheet a couple of weeks ago by using firebug.  I have tried modifying the dimensions in the theme stylesheet and the custom app stylesheet with no luck. I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. change your `#content` css width to : `width:657px;`
   And play with the margin to get it the same way

Check your sidebar too it's definitively different, maybe you wont have to modify the content if you modify the sidebar

1. you have two time the class `#nav` remove the one without the `background-image`
2. Resize the height of your class #title :  `#title{height: 34px;}`
   But one more time you have to class #title, so remove the one that as a bigger heigth thant 34px
3. Remove the color here : `#nav a:link { text-decoration: none;}`

5.You need to add this class to the link that is active : `#nav a.active {background: url("/themes/a3_atlantis/active_overlay.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;color: #0B486B;height: 24px;}`

Lots of modification ;)
OR juste remove the duplicates classes and it will help a lot ! !

Comment: I have tried a couple of these with no luck, but I think I will just remove the dup classes when I get a chance.  I will keep you posted and I will mark this correct when I remove them.  I appreciate the answer.